# Stripe useStripe() and useElements() both are null and elements do not render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm unable to get the  to render and both useStripe() and useElements() have null null values within my payment form. I believe the issued is caused by the stripe promise which is not resolving but I cannot figure out why it is happening or how to fix it.

Stripe Container:

```
interface SubPlanPaymentPageProps {
  subscription: Subscription | null;
}
const PUBLIC_TEST_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXX';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(PUBLIC_TEST_KEY);

const SubPlanPaymentPage: React.FC<SubPlanPaymentPageProps> = ({subscription}) => {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');

  const options = {
    clientSecret,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/payment/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({subscription}),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
  
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
          <StripePaymentForm />
          <button onClick={()=> console.log(stripePromise)}>secret</button>
          // this logs: Promise {<pending>}
        </Elements>
      )
     }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Payment Form:

```
export default function StripePaymentForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSubcribe = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
   
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
       // this right here logs: stripe: null, elements: null
      console.log('stripe:', stripe, 'elements:', elements);
      return;
    }

    console.log('stripe:', stripe, 'elements:', elements);

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);
    if (!cardElement) {
      return;
    }

    const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'John Doe',
      },
    });

    if (error) {
      console.error('error:', error);
    } else {
      console.log(paymentMethod);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='payment-form-container'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubcribe}>
        <div className='row'>
          <CardElement /> // this does not render
        </div>
        <button>Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried initializing the stripe with a useEffect() but that didn't work.

```
useEffect(()=> {
  const initStripe = async () => {
      const stripeInstance = await loadStripe('your-publishable-key');
      setStripePromise(stripeInstance)
  }
  initStripe();
},[])
```

Comment: Try a simplified reproduction with a hardcoded PaymentIntent `client_secret` as shown here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react. That will help simplify the components and make it easier to compare against your code.

Comment: When using a hardcoded Payment internet <CardElement /> still doesn't render and the stripe promise doesn't resolve.